# Помогите расставить знаки препинания в предложении (2)

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите, пожалуйста, расставить знаки препинания в предложении:

*"Они в своем большинстве до 90 % состоят из включений, и только небольшая часть около 10 % представлена основным компонентом, например, на медных месторождениях минералом халькопиритом, а на полиметаллических – сфалеритом"*

Comment: В чем конкретно у вас проблема? Понимаете, тут не сервис для выполнения "домашних заданий". Вопрос должен быть поставлен так, чобы было, что обсудить, а не просто сделать чужую работу.

Comment: В знаках препинания.
Правильно ли их расставляю?
_Они в своем большинстве (до 90 %) состоят из включений, и только небольшая часть около (10 %) представлена основным компонентом, например, на медных месторождениях, -- минералом халькопиритом, а на полиметаллических – сфалеритом_

Comment: *В знаках препинания. Правильно ли их расставляю* - конкретно, какие именно знаки вызывают сомнения.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы оформила это предложение так:
**Они в своем большинстве состоят из включений, и только небольшая часть (около 10 %) содержит основные компоненты, например: минерал халькопирит — на медных месторождениях, сфалерит — на полиметаллических.**

1. Ненормальны **в одном** предложении прописные истины: 90% + 10% = 100%.
   Достаточно количество процентов указать только раз.
2. "Основным компонентом" — это один компонент (ед. ч.). Вы же указываете два компонента (халькопирит и сфалерит), значит, нужно множественное число.
3. Вместо "представлены" лучше использовать "содержат".
4. В конце предложения необходима точка.

Answer (score 0):

**Они в своем большинстве (до 90 %) состоят из включений, и только небольшая часть (около 10 %) представлена основным компонентом, например на медных месторождениях — минералом халькопиритом, а на полиметаллических — сфалеритом.**

Запятая после "например" не нужна, так как это слово выступает здесь в роли присоединительного союза для уточняющего оборота.